# How do i implement nunit correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, openai-api

Tried implementing https://github.com/OkGoDoIt/OpenAI-API-dotnet/tree/v1.7.2 into my unity project and also implemented the latest version of both nunit and newtonsoft.
But i get these 3 errors everytime:
Assets\nunit-3.13.3\src\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs(50,8): error CS1029: #error: 'Missing AssemblyConfiguration attribute for this target.'
Assets\nunit-3.13.3\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(62,8): error CS1029: #error: 'Missing AssemblyTitle attribute for this target.'
Assets\nunit-3.13.3\src\NUnitFramework\nunitlite\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(45,8): error CS1029: #error: 'Missing AssemblyTitle attribute for this target.'

i tried solving this issue with chatgpt but it told me that my code was correct and i shouldnt be getting these errors

Comment: instead of NUnit you could use Unity's own [Test Framework Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@2.0/manual/index.html) .. (which contains also a custom build of NUnit 3.5) as well as the [Newtonsoft Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) - both installed via the [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)

Comment: and well regarding your last sentence ... ChatGPT can tell you whatever it wants ... if your compiler says there are compiler errors ... well, then that means there are compiler errors ;)

Comment: ty ill be trying that

Comment: i already had it installed as it seems, maybe it installed itself automatically?

Comment: yes, possible that they are already included by default when creating a new project using the Hub's templates